# Synchronization syntax for access to concurrent collection

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, synchronization

I have the following code:

```
public class State {
    private List<Position> m_track;

    public State() {
        m_track = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Position>());
    }

    public List<Position> getTrack() {
        return m_track;
    }
}

// in different class
public void modifyTrack(State _state) {
    List<Position> local_track = _state.getTrack();
    synchronized (local_track) {
        // safely modify track
    }
}
```

But Android Studio gives me a warning on line `synchronized (local_track)`:

> Synchronization on local variable 'local_track' Reports
>   synchronization on a local variable or parameter.
>
> It is very difficult to guarantee correctness when such synchronization is used.
>
> It may be possible to improve code like this by controlling access through e.g. a synchronized wrapper class, or by synchronizing on a field.

If I replace `synchronized (local_track)` with `synchronized (_state.getTrack())` warning goes away.

If I understand correctly my `local_track` is just a reference and no new object is created and if so why can't I synchronize on it?

Comment: Just ignore it. It doesn't know what it's talking about.

Comment: @EJP, thank you very much

Comment: And read about Java naming conventions. "_" is for SOME_CONSTANT only. You don't use it anywhere else. And that "m_" to indicate "its a field" is also discouraged by most java coding style guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with EJPs comment - in this case, it is safe to ignore the warning for the "multi-threading" aspect of it.

But: I still think the warning is a symptom of "bad practice". You see: you **externalize** that list to users of your `State`class; and worse: and then that user class *locks* on that list; probably to then modify it.

That is the **opposite** of good OO. You make an internal implementation detail known to the public; and you even intend to modify that internal data structure!

In my eyes, this is violating various principles, such as [TDA](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) or simple "information hiding".

Thus: in response to this warning; you might want to step back and look at your design more closely; and see for example if there is a way to have the **State** class do those modifications to its track list!

Comment: oops, actually, instead of "safely modify track" comment should be "safely iterate track" :) That way it seems like a tolerable design solution

Comment: Even then: locking on that thing looks "wrong" to me. You might instead have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845778/thread-safety-when-iterating-through-an-arraylist-using-foreach) and use a different kind of list that makes it **safe** to iterate it.

Comment: well, I replaced `Collections.synchronizedList` with `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and it seems like more simple and good-looking solution, thanks for your input and links

Comment: You are very welcome! Glad I could tell you more than "ignore it" ;-)