# How to make java.util.ArrayList threadsafe

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrentmodification

I have logic similar to below in my program which throws `ConcurrentModificationException`. How can I make `java.util.ArrayList` threadsafe other than using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (because I have large number of write on this list and as per my understanding writes are expensive on CopyOnWriteArrayList)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test extends Thread {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.start();

        System.out.println("in main thred");

        t.destory();

    }

    public void destory() {
        list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println("done");

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            list.add("test");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
in main thred
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444005/how-do-i-make-my-arraylist-thread-safe-another-approach-to-problem-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845778/thread-safety-when-iterating-through-an-arraylist-using-foreach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my ArrayList Thread-Safe? Another approach to problem in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444005/how-do-i-make-my-arraylist-thread-safe-another-approach-to-problem-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to synchronize all accesses to the list:

```
public void destory() {
    synchronized (list) {
      list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
    }
    System.out.println("done");

}
```

and

```
    while(true) {
      synchronized (list) {
        list.add("test");
      }
    }
```

Note that it is not sufficient simply to wrap the list in `Collections.synchronizedList`, since that won't hold the monitor for the entirety of the iteration by the stream.

Comment: But there is no need for using the Stream API here. When replacing the `list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);` with `list.toArray(new String[0]);`, using `synchronizedList` would work.